# How to fix an unknown right margin that only shows on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have created a website that works perfectly fine on my desktop, but for some reason it shows a margin on the right that is totally unexpected. Tried to mimic other's solution on StackOverflow but still failed to see any difference. Please Help!

I tried removing paddings, margins, and left/right position, but I still failed to get it moving for even an inch. :(

Website: http://tobyio.com 
Code: https://github.com/Soundpulse/soundpulse.github.io

Image showing how it looks like right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWOOI.jpg

Comment: try to go in you devtools and delete one element at the time, to understand which one is causing the issue. Then narrow it down to its children too. Once you have a more specific understanding of the issue post another question ;)

Comment: I have no idea which of the elements is causing the issue though, The only way i got it working on mobile devices is to remove all sections as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted this sections

```
<section id="showcase">
<section id="resume">
```

and it worked , may be you have a fixed width or o position issue somewhere.
- as @threeFatCat said, you can use overflow:hidden for both sections

Answer (score 0):

I cannot view your picture due to corporate policy in our browser for shared images. But base on your link, if you're talking about the scrollbar that shows horizontally. Add this to your `<section id="resume">`:

`overflow:hidden;`

It looks like it fixed the problem, I'm using dev tools, but it would be best if you can paste here your brief code. Try it first.

**Edit**
If in case `overflow:hidden;` is giving you design issue in other resolutions(which I have not checked). It would be best if you specifically apply this `css` with [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will help you:

```
section:not(#sidebar) {
 margin-left: auto;
 width: calc((100% - 15%) - 20px);
} 
.container {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```